# Is there a way to inspect the CIL evaluation stack within code?

Tags: cil

I have a set of CIL code that is not working as expected. My question is, Is there a way to inspect or peek the evaluation stack at any point?

Thanks

Comment: No, [use this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/peverify-exe-peverify-tool).